# How can I get an array with a nested array whose elements have a unique order?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays. How can I get an array with a nested array whose elements have a unique order?

What I have:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

I think, that I can format to JSON, and get my result with filter and indexOf ,I have tried this:

```
var unique = x2.map(ar=>JSON.stringify(ar).replace(/[\[\]']+/g,''))
  .filter((itm, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(itm) === idx);
```

Comment: Do you have another example?

Comment: [[1, 2, 35, 7], [1, 2, 3], [35, 7],  [3, 4], [4]] => [[1, 2, 35, 7], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4]].

Comment: Order of the elemenets is important:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 2, 3], [35, 7], [3, 4], [4]] --> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 2, 3], [35, 7]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try, I first sorted the array by its length then applied `filter` and match the index position by making use of `every` and `includes`. Here is an example:

```js
var example = [[1, 2, 35, 7], [1, 2, 3], [35, 7], [3, 4], [4]];

var result = example.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length).filter((k,i,self)=>self.findIndex(p=>k.every(l=>p.includes(l)))==i);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But, the order of the elements is important. I wanted to remove the elements if the order of the elements completely entered.
Example:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 2, 3], [35, 7], [3, 4], [4]] -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 2, 3], [35, 7]];

Comment: @bruce I should have mentioned about this in my solution. Can you also give this a try: `example.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length).filter((k,i,self)=>self.findIndex((p,c)=>k.every((l,j)=>p.includes(l) && (p[j]==l || p[p.length-1]===l)))==i)`

Comment: I have corrected your method:

example.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length).map(ar => JSON.stringify(ar).replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '')).filter((k, i, self) => self.findIndex(p => p.includes(k)) === i);

Thanks you! But, can can i do with less algorithm complexity ?